# Rails cant save correct date into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have a date format like this "18/12/15" as input (it is a string)

```
18 => day
12 => month 
15 => year (2015)
```

I am trying to store it in my db in a date column but it doesnt save the proper date (for the previous exemple I get  Sat, 15 Dec 2018 whereas I should get something like day, 18 Dec 2015.)

How can I fix that

Comment: what is your locale set to?

Comment: where can I check that ?

Comment: @DavidGeismar: try `I18n.locale`

Comment: I have a locales folder in config but with a lot of different yml files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime):

```
require 'date'
Date.strptime('18/12/15', '%d/%m/%y')
#<Date: 2015-12-18 ((2457375j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to define a date with the order of day, month, year, while, due to the locale your intention is interpreted as year, month, day.

You can do one of the following:

- pass the parameters in inverted order
- implement a method which gets the parameters in the correct order and inverts them
- set the locale to the one you intend to use
- use `strptime`, as spickermann described